# tomcat works but service tomcat status says it failed

Tags: linux, redhat, tomcat, java, service

This is my tomcat.service file, located at etc/systemd/system

```
[root@ip-10-81-27-248 system]# less tomcat.service 

Systemd unit file for tomcat

[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
SuccessExitStatus=143

Environment=TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest/jre
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -  Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

now when i check the status of my tomcat it says

**ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**

```
[root@ip-10-81-27-248 system]# service tomcat status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l tomcat.service
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-04-25 02:43:57 UTC; 6min ago
  Process: 16187 ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16154 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16164 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 25 02:43:54 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
Apr 25 02:43:54 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal startup.sh[16154]: Existing PID file found during start.
Apr 25 02:43:54 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal startup.sh[16154]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Apr 25 02:43:54 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal startup.sh[16154]: Tomcat started.
Apr 25 02:43:54 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Apr 25 02:43:57 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 25 02:43:57 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Apr 25 02:43:57 ip-10-81-27-248.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

i tried using service tomcat restart but it still says tomcat service failed.
what may be the cause this?

Comment: Did you look at this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235891/tomcat-8-will-not-start-after-initial-install

Answer (score 1):

Here's an error:

```
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -  Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
                                                 ^^
```

Remove those two spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have referred  [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235891/tomcat-8-will-not-start-after-initial-install)
and  giving tomcat user ownership of the whole tomcat directory worked for me

`cd /opt && sudo chown -R tomcat tomcat/`